# C++ Too few arguments to function ‘WINBOOL GetProcessIoCounters(HANDLE, PIO_COUNTERS)’

Tags: c++

I am trying to fix a piece of C++ code that I have come across whilst doing a course.

I am compiling the `churrasco.cpp` file with the below command on Debian...

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc Churrasco.cpp -lws2_32 -o churrasco.exe
```

I initially had this error with a suggestion by the compiler to change a function...

```
root@kali:~/Churrasco# i686-w64-mingw32-gcc Churrasco.cpp -lws2_32 -o churrasco.exe
Churrasco.cpp: In function ‘DWORD RunCommandAsSystem(HANDLE, LPSTR)’:
Churrasco.cpp:125:22: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘LPSTR’ {aka ‘char*’} [-Wwrite-strings]
     sInfo.lpDesktop= "WinSta0\\Default";
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Churrasco.cpp:147:112: warning: passing NULL to non-pointer argument 7 of ‘WINBOOL CreateProcessAsUserA(HANDLE, LPCSTR, LPSTR, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, WINBOOL, DWORD, LPVOID, LPCSTR, LPSTARTUPINFOA, LPPROCESS_INFORMATION)’ [-Wconversion-null]
 dwRes=CreateProcessAsUser(hToken2, lpComspec, lpCommandTmp, NULL, NULL, TRUE, NULL, NULL, NULL, &sInfo, &pInfo);
                                                                                                               ^

Churrasco.cpp: In function ‘void* GetSystemToken(HANDLE, DWORD)’:
Churrasco.cpp:226:50: warning: passing NULL to non-pointer argument 2 of ‘void* OpenProcess(DWORD, WINBOOL, DWORD)’ [-Wconversion-null]
  hProcess=OpenProcess(PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE,NULL,Pid);
                                                  ^
Churrasco.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, _TCHAR**)’:
Churrasco.cpp:332:31: error: ‘GetProcessIdOfThread’ was not declared in this scope
    if (hThread && dwRpcssPid==GetProcessIdOfThread(hThread)) {
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Churrasco.cpp:332:31: note: suggested alternative: ‘GetProcessIoCounters’ // This was the suggested change
    if (hThread && dwRpcssPid==GetProcessIdOfThread(hThread)) {
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                               GetProcessIoCounters
```

I did so and the segment of code now looks like so...

```
if (hThread && dwRpcssPid==GetProcessIoCounters(hThread)) { 
                printf ("/churrasco/-->Found Thread: %d \n",Tid);
```

The issue I have now is that I have the below error and I do not know enough about C++ to fix it quickly.

```
Churrasco.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, _TCHAR**)’:
Churrasco.cpp:332:59: error: too few arguments to function ‘WINBOOL GetProcessIoCounters(HANDLE, PIO_COUNTERS)’
    if (hThread && dwRpcssPid==GetProcessIoCounters(hThread)) {
                                                           ^
In file included from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/windows.h:70,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/winsock2.h:23,
                 from stdafx.h:10,
                 from Churrasco.cpp:18:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/winbase.h:1153:29: note: declared here
```

So my question is, what arguments do I need to place or what changes to the new function need to be made to resolve this error?

EDIT:

I added the reference to...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Processthreadsapi.h"
```

but still have the below error:

```
Churrasco.cpp: In function ‘void* GetSystemToken(HANDLE, DWORD)’:
Churrasco.cpp:227:50: warning: passing NULL to non-pointer argument 2 of ‘void* OpenProcess(DWORD, WINBOOL, DWORD)’ [-Wconversion-null]
  hProcess=OpenProcess(PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE,NULL,Pid);
                                                  ^
Churrasco.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, _TCHAR**)’:
Churrasco.cpp:333:31: error: ‘GetProcessIdOfThread’ was not declared in this scope
    if (hThread && dwRpcssPid==GetProcessIdOfThread(hThread)) {
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Churrasco.cpp:333:31: note: suggested alternative: ‘GetProcessIoCounters’
    if (hThread && dwRpcssPid==GetProcessIdOfThread(hThread)) {
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                               GetProcessIoCounters
(base) root@kali:~/Churrasco#
```

Working Folder:

```
(base) root@kali:~/Churrasco# ls
32892.txt      Churrasco.ncb  Churrasco.suo     Iphlpapi.h  Processthreadsapi.h  stdafx.cpp
Churrasco.cpp  Churrasco.sln  Churrasco.vcproj  Ntsecapi.h  ReadMe.txt           stdafx.h
```

Answer (score 2):

The *suggested alternative* provided by the compiler is its best guess of what identifier you wanted, assuming that what you typed is a misspelling (typo).  In your case, though, the identifier is correct but the proper header was not included.  You do not want to change the name of the function you are calling.

[`GetProcessIdOfThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getprocessidofthread) is defined in the `processthreadsapi.h` header, so you need to add

```
#include <processthreadsapi.h>
```

to your source file.

Comment: Thanks for the help mate, but I still have the same issue. See edited original question.

Comment: @3therk1ll Looking in the header, it looks like the `_WIN32_WINNT` macro needs to be at least `0x0600` with `WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION` set to either `WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP` or `WINAPI_PARTITION_SYSTEM`.

Comment: I'll be running this on a Win2K3 box, so something like this? 
`#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600`.  Looking on MSDN I can this is specific for Win2K3: `#define _WIN32_WINNT_WS03  0x0502`
Not being lazy sorry, I'm just at work so will have to test it this evening